# Looping through an array to check a condition

Tags: c

I'm using a FOR loop to loop through an array to check a condition but it seems to duplicate the variables I want to print.
Here's my code:

```
    /*Printing the matrix*/
    for(row=0;row<15;row++)
    {
        for(col=0;col<8;col++)
        {
            for(a=0;a<sizeof(row_sel)/(sizeof(row_sel[0]));a++)
            {
                if(row==row_sel[a] && col==col_sel[a])
                {
                    printf("|%d|",matrix[row][col]);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf(" %d ",matrix[row][col]);
                }
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

What I'm trying to print is:

```
 |0|   6    7    3    6    6    9    5
  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
  2    8    8    4    8    4    0    0
  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
  5    0    8    7    9    5    5    3
  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
  2    7    8    5    3    3    8    6
  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
  6    6    4    2    9    6    2    1
  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
  9    4    0    6    6    7    0    4
  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
  4    3    8    9    0    2    2    7
  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
  0    3    6    7    8    3    5   |2|
```

But instead I get this output, I don't know why the values are duplicated,the loop should've ended or skipped the statement:

```
|0| 0  0  1  1  1  2  2  2  7  7  7  7  7  7  3  3  3  6  6  6  1  1  1
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  6  6  6  3  3  3  2  2  2  0  0  0  4  4  4  2  2  2  9  9  9
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 5  5  5  4  4  4  6  6  6  3  3  3  5  5  5  8  8  8  6  6  6  5  5  5
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 5  5  5  7  7  7  1  1  1  9  9  9  1  1  1  2  2  2  0  0  0  4  4  4
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 9  9  9  7  7  7  3  3  3  6  6  6  8  8  8  0  0  0  3  3  3  8  8  8
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 5  5  5  2  2  2  6  6  6  5  5  5  2  2  2  7  7  7  5  5  5  5  5  5
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 5  5  5  7  7  7  8  8  8  3  3  3  2  2  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  6  6  6
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 9  9  9  6  6  6  9  9  9  7  7  7  2  2  2  6  6  6  2  2  2  5 |5| 5
```

Any tips to where I went wrong? Any help is quite appreciated.

Comment: @achal I wanted to print |%d| if the value is found in the row_sel array and col_sel array if the row and col value match up with the value in both arrays.

Answer (score 1):

**Your problem:**

You print each value of the matrix for *every* a, but you only want to print it once.

**The solution:**

You have to move the if-else statement out of the innermost loop:

```
for(row=0;row<15;row++)
{
    for(col=0;col<8;col++)
    {
        bool foundMatch = false;
        for(a=0;!foundMatch && a<sizeof(row_sel)/(sizeof(row_sel[0]));a++)
        {
            foundMatch = row==row_sel[a] && col==col_sel[a];
        }
        if(foundMatch)
        {
            printf("|%d|",matrix[row][col]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf(" %d ",matrix[row][col]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

**Why/How it works:**

The inner loop will run until `foundMatch` is true, or `a` gets out of range.

`foundMatch` is set to true if there is any `a` for which `row==row_sel[a] && col==col_sel[a]` is `true`.

`|%d|` will print if `foundMatch` is true.

Comment: but can I implement it inside the loop?

Comment: so for my understanding, using stdbool library, foundMatch is initialized to false. In the for loop, if the foundMatch matches the condition which is foundMatch=true AND a< array length. The below printf statement |%d| will print?